# Documentation feature request: See Also

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

I think the "See Also" section of the official PHP documentation is one of it's strongest features and think that all documentation should have a "See Also" section to link related items.

I was looking around in the regular expression area of Documentation and thought that it would be great to link certain related items together (like the tokens: `^`, `$`, `\A`, etc.)

Comment: You mean http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/add-a-linked-related-topics-section-like-on-q-a?noredirect=1 or http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/do-we-need-custom-syntax-sugar-for-topic-page-links?noredirect=1 ? Yeah it doesn't seem like it when you look at the result but we made a lot of feedbacks during the private beta.

Comment: @Knu docs-beta.stackexchange still exists? That's weird.

Comment: either see also or by links it should be possible to specify "further information" kind of thing

Comment: @tktsubota these will eventually be migrated to meta SO.

Comment: @Knu while those types of things (tags, algorithm generated "related" questions) are helpful, I don't see how the algorithm could catch all the possibly related topics. Much better to have something that is user-contributed, because humans would know the intricacies of the topic much better. I also think something right in the main content would be better than something in a sidebar. Makes it more visible, more important.